# Safe Empty State in Constructors and Bool within C++:

Tags: c++

In my code I am doing the following, but I am not sure if I am allowed to or if it is a good practice in C++. I need to create a safe empty constructor, but I also need a constructor that initializes the variables given the parameters. So I am doing the following:

This is the Traveler.h File:

```
namespace sict
{
// TODO: define the constants here

const int max_destination_size = 32;
const int max_name_size = 16;

// TODO: define the Traveler class here

class Traveler
{
private:
    char fName[max_name_size];
    char lName[max_name_size];
    char dest[max_destination_size];
public:
    // Empty Constructor.
    Traveler();
    // Constructor that accepts 3 parameters.
    Traveler(char* fn, char* ln, char* dt);
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void display() const;
};
```

This is Traveler.cpp File:

```
namespace sict
{
// TODO: implement the default constructor here
Traveler::Traveler()
{

}
// TODO: implement the constructor with 3 parameters here
Traveler::Traveler(char* fn, char* ln, char* dt)
{
    if (&fn != nullptr || &ln != nullptr || dt != nullptr)
    {

    }

}
// TODO: implement isEmpty query here
bool Traveler::isEmpty() const
{

}
// TODO: implement display query here
void Traveler::display() const
{

}

}
```

The instructions for the Empty Constructor are as followed:

*default constructor (a no-argument constructor): this constructor sets the Traveler object to a safe empty state.*

I am familiar with setting variables to empty states but a little confused on how to set a constructor to an empty state.

The instructions for the bool and display functions are as followed:

*bool isEmpty() const: a query that reports if the Traveler object is in a safe empty state.*

*void display() const: a query that displays the contents of the Traveler object in the following format (see also the output listing below).*

I am unfamiliar with the concept of query in this portion of the code. Although i know that queries are used to report the state of an object, i do not know how they are used and declared.

Comment: Begin by defining a "safe empty state" for your type. Either have an explicit flag that says "this isn't okay to use" or some combination of your existing member variables that say "this isn't okay to use". Then put code in your default constructor to set the object to that state.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in the three-argument constructor, `&fn != nullptr` and `&ln != nullptr` are wrong. `fn` is an argument to the function, so its address will never be a null pointer. Test the **value** of the argument, not its address.

Comment: Note that the `char *` parameters should probably be `const char *`.

Answer (score 0):

As Pete Becker pointed out, it is you to decide what **safe empty state** means for your own data type.

When your object is instantiated with the *default constructor* your c-style strings (fName, lName and dest) will only contain random/garbage values inside them.

So any further use of your object will most likely lead to *unwanted results*.

You could initialize your c-style strings as empty strings in the *default constructor* and then make the **isEmpty()** function check if one (or all) of those strings is actually empty. 
Please note that this can be avoided if you use the **std::string** class (which I recommend you to use from now on).

Eventually, you could just remove the *default constructor* from the class, so that anytime an object is instantiated you **must** fill in the strings with a value.